# How to remove Left Win button from Level 3 in setxkbmap?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, x11

I wish to use 'Left Win' button to switch keyboard layouts. This works fine on my PC: I just added two keyboards in Xfce4 and defined 'Left Win' as a switch: [screenshot of xfce keyboard layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07u39.png)

I have the next setxkbmap on my PC that works fine:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru
variant:    ,
options:    compose:sclk,grp:lwin_toggle
```

But the same configs in Xfce4 Keyboard layouts do not work on laptop. I noticed that on Laptop I also have this in setxkbmap:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     ru,us
variant:    ,
options:    grp:lwin_toggle,lv3:lwin_switch
```

and this does not work. I think that the reason is that **'Left Win' presents in both grp and lv3 options**, and this makes it is not working.

How can I remove option '**lv3:lwin_switch**' from setxkbmap the easiest way?

Update 2022-08-07 01:16 utc:
I just found how to remove options from setxkbmap with [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1895978#p1895978)

```
setxkbmap -option
```

But when I set 'Left Win' for switch keyboard, I get again unworkable config:

```
$ setxkbmap -query -print
xkb_keymap {
 xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
 xkb_types     { include "complete" };
 xkb_compat    { include "complete" };
 xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ru+us:2+inet(evdev)+group(lwin_toggle)+level3(lwin_switch)" };
 xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     ru,us
variant:    ,
options:    grp:lwin_toggle,lv3:lwin_switch
```

I think it is a bug of my version of xfce4:

```
$ xfce4-panel -V
Gtk-Message: 04:19:48.448: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
xfce4-panel 4.12.2 (Xfce 4.12)
```

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

with these links [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1895978#p1895978), [devuan installation](https://dev1galaxy.org/viewtopic.php?id=4351) and also reading manuals

```
man setxkbmap
man xkeyboard-config
```

I fixed my own problem. That was a mistake during installation of Devuan, when it asked configuration of keyboard. I ran under root:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and chose keyboard, language, and AltGear key, compose key. I chose to none, and after that I could set 'Left Win' for keyboard switch in Xfce4 settings.

Also i can do it manually with this:

```
setxkbmap -option
setxkbmap -option 'grp:lwin_toggle'
```

First line just erase all the options from setxkbmap, the second line adds option for keyboard switch. But this works only for current session, not permanently.

Refining my question: What set 'Left Win' as level3 key? - That was xorg settings, that I fixed with `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. How to set 'Left Win' for keyboard switch? - Go to Keyboard settings, and disable standard configurations, add layouts and set 'Left Win' as keyboard switch. But be sure xorg configs do not break it, check xorg configs under root:  `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.